# Realm query update not reflected in RealmRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, realm

Been using realm and it's awesome.

Came up against something.  Wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

I have a `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` that I'm using to show the results of a realm query.  This works perfectly if I add or update records in the realm.  I had to `setHasFixedSize(false)` on the recycler view to get it to update on the fly.  Not sure if this is correct but it worked.

Anyway, that's not my issue.

I'm experimenting with filtering my data.  I have the following query:

```
realm.where(Person::class.java).contains("name", nameFilter, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAllSorted("name")
```

I'm passing this RealmResults to my recycler view and it works great on add/update.

However, when I attempt a filter, it doesn't update automatically.

Am I right in saying that simply changing my filter (specified by `nameFilter`) isn't enough for the query to be re-run?  This would be fair enough I suppose.  Since I guess there's no trigger for realm to know I've changed the value of the string.

However, even if I recalculate my query, it doesn't seem to update in the Recycler View unless I explicitly call `updateData` on my adapter.  I'm not sure if this is the best or most efficient way to do this.  Is there a better way?

**Complete Code:**

**Main Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    private val TAG: String = this::class.java.simpleName

    private val realm: Realm = Realm.getInstance(RealmConfiguration.Builder().deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build())

    private var nameFilter = ""

    private var allPersons: RealmResults<Person> = realm.where(Person::class.java).contains("name", nameFilter, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAllSorted("name")

    private val adapter: PersonRecyclerViewAdapter = PersonRecyclerViewAdapter(allPersons)

    private lateinit var disposable: Disposable

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        realm.executeTransaction({
//            realm.deleteAll()
        })

        Log.i(TAG, "Deleted all objects from Realm")

        buttonAddOrUpdatePerson.setOnClickListener(this)

        setUpRecyclerView()

        disposable = RxTextView.textChangeEvents(editTextNameFilter)
//                .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) // default Scheduler is Computation
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith<DisposableObserver<TextViewTextChangeEvent>>(getSearchObserver())

    }

    private fun getSearchObserver(): DisposableObserver<TextViewTextChangeEvent> {
        return object : DisposableObserver<TextViewTextChangeEvent>() {
            override fun onComplete() {
                Log.i(TAG,"--------- onComplete")
            }

            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                Log.i(TAG, "--------- Woops on error!")
            }

            override fun onNext(onTextChangeEvent: TextViewTextChangeEvent) {
                nameFilter = editTextNameFilter.text.toString()

                allPersons = realm.where(Person::class.java).contains("name", nameFilter, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAllSorted("name")

                // this is necessary or the recycler view doesn't update
                adapter.updateData(allPersons)

                Log.d(TAG, "Filter: $nameFilter")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        realm.close()
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        if(view == null) return

        when(view) {
            buttonAddOrUpdatePerson -> handleAddOrUpdatePerson()
        }
    }

    private fun handleAddOrUpdatePerson() {
        val personToAdd = Person()
        personToAdd.name = editTextName.text.toString()
        personToAdd.email = editTextEmail.text.toString()

        realm.executeTransactionAsync({
            bgRealm -> bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(personToAdd)
        })
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
        recyclerViewPersons.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerViewPersons.adapter = adapter
        recyclerViewPersons.setHasFixedSize(false)
        recyclerViewPersons.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))
    }
}
```

**PersonRecyclerViewAdapter**

```
internal class PersonRecyclerViewAdapter(data: OrderedRealmCollection<Person>?, autoUpdate: Boolean = true) : RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Person, PersonRecyclerViewAdapter.PersonViewHolder>(data, autoUpdate) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PersonViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.person_row, parent, false)

        return PersonViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PersonViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        if(holder == null || data == null) return

        val personList = data ?: return

        val person = personList[position]

        holder.bind(person)
    }

    internal class PersonViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var textViewName: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNameDisplay)
        var textViewEmail: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmailDisplay)

        internal fun bind(person: Person) {
            textViewEmail.text = person.email
            textViewName.text = person.name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I explicitly call updateData on my adapter. I'm not sure if this is the best or most efficient way to do this. Is there a better way?` no

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, `updateData()` is the way to do it. Since you updated the query, the `Results` you want to show becomes a different object. `updateData()` has to be called to notify the adapter that the data source is changed.

However, you may lose the nice animation for the RecyclerView in this way since the whole view will be refreshed because of the data source is changed. There are some ways to work around this.

eg.: You can add one field `isSelected` to `Person`. Query the results by `isSelected` field and pass it to the adaptor:

```
allPersons = realm.where(Person::class.java).equalTo("isSelected", true).findAllSorted("name")
adapter = PersonRecyclerViewAdapter(allPersons)
```

When changing the query:

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync({
    var allPersons = realm.where(Person::class.java).equalTo("isSelected", true).findAllSorted("name")
    for (person in allPersons) person.isSelected = false; // Clear the list first
    allPersons = realm.where(Person::class.java).contains("name", nameFilter, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAllSorted("name") // new query
    for (person in allPersons) person.isSelected = true;
    })
```

It depends on your use case, if the list to show is long, this approach might be slow, you could try to add all the filtered person to a `RealmList` and set the `RealmList` as the data source of the adapter. `RealmList.clear()` is a fast opration than iterating the whole results set to set the `isSelected` field.

If the filter will mostly cause the whole view gets refreshed, `updateData()` is simply good enough, just use it then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thinking about it some more, I guess it should have been obvious that the add/update works because it's the same query object. But in the case of the filter, the query needs to be re-run and is therefore a new object that the adapter is not aware of which is why we need to call updateData. Is there some way to get the query to re-run thereby updating the original object?